# Different Way to Render Same Results of Associated Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations, unique

I have 3 models: Campaigns, Weeks and Creatives

A campaign can have many weeks and weeks can have many creatives.

**Campaign Model**

```
has_many :weeks, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :weeks, :allow_destroy => :true
validates_associated :weeks

has_many :creatives, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :creatives, :allow_destroy => :true
```

**Week Model**

```
belongs_to :campaign


has_many :creative_weeks
has_many :creatives, :through => :creative_weeks
```

**Creative Model**

```
belongs_to :campaign

has_many :creative_weeks
has_many :weeks, :through => :creative_weeks
```

Within the campaign view, I have:

```
   <% @campaign.weeks.each do |week| %>
     <%= render week.creatives %>
   <% end %>
```

The resulting log of this is:

```
Creative Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `creatives`.* FROM `creatives` INNER JOIN `creative_weeks` ON `creatives`.`id` = `creative_weeks`.`creative_id` WHERE `creative_weeks`.`week_id` = 6
```

Basically, only showing the creatives that belong to that particular week.

I am trying to create custom galleries, etc and needing to bring this code locally into a partial verses having it <%= render week.creatives %>

Based on the log provided, is there a way for me to achieve the same filtered results using 'includes', 'join' etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. by using through associations on your campaign model:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :weeks
   has_many :creatives, through: :weeks
end
```

and now you can use:

```
<% @campaign.creatives.each do |creative| %>
   <%= image_tag(...) %>
<% end %>
```

If you need to show/hide based ont he week that a creative belongs to... you can still check the week like this:

```
<% @campaign.creatives.each do |creative| %>
   <%= image_tag(...) if user.can_see_week?(creative.week) %>
<% end %>
```

(or whatever week-checking method that you use)

or if you really want to scope creatives by weeks then make a week-scope on creatives:

```
<% @campaign.creatives.where(week: user.allowed_weeks).each do |creative| %>
   <%= image_tag(...) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I should have been more clear. Campaigns have MANY weeks to them. Each week can have multiple creatives. Campaign does have an association to creatives and I could display it like this without a problem, but there is more to the equation. Only certain people are supposed to see these images based on if they are the week owner or not. That is why it is important for me to filter the creative through the pertaining week

Comment: In other words "I have not included all the relevant code in my question yet"... please fix that, and then we can really help you :)
(don't describe it to me in comments... edit your question and add the code there...)

Comment: right... unfortunately you haven't explained how weeks are checked for a user... but I've made a stab at a solution anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing duplicates this way, you can add uniq to has_many through.

```
has_many :weeks
has_many :creatives, -> { uniq }, through: :weeks
```

Comment: Sorry. The unique call did not work. I had tried that earlier without success.